# 32 bit R and 64 bit R: output differs

Tags: r

I've made a script to predict wage based on the variables:gender, age and education. I use the rpart function. When i run the code in 32-bit R, the output differs from the 64-bit R version. The difference is not dramatically, but I can't decide which output is correct.

The data set is quite large (10,000+ entries). because of privacy reasons i'm not permitted to share data/results.

this is the code i use:

```
set.seed(1234)
tree <-rpart(wage ~  gender + age + education, method='class', data=Data, control=rpart.control(minsplit=1, minbucket=1, cp=0.002))
```

How can i get the correct output in both versions of R? Can the GMP package help me? If yes, how?

Comment: Does setting a seed before, e.g.  `set.seed(123)`, give equal results?

Comment: unfortunately not. it still gives different output

Comment: Define "correct".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to manually set the seed parameters.  Like this ...

```
set.seed(1234, kind = "Mersenne-Twister", normal.kind = "Inversion");
mean(rnorm(1000))
```

This gives the same result on 32 and 64 bit.